# Check index of an array and print variable in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexing

I have 2 variable arrays:

```
var a = [22, 34, 56,22]
var b = [red, blue, yellow, gray ]
```

I check index of array `a`, where have value `22`, the index is `0` and `3` then I print `var b[0]` and `b[3]` and I get `Red` and `Gray`.

How do I do this with/in Jquery?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you want? What is "how to make it with JQUERY Script"?

Comment: **jQuery**, not JQUERY. It's not an acronym.

Comment: sorry for my english :( , i want this in programmally jquery , can you help me ?

Comment: @meagar i will edit, thanks before :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean this?

```
  var a = [22, 34, 56, 22];
  var b = ["red", "blue", "yellow", "gray"];
  var input = 22;

  var matches = $.map(a, function (o, i) { //Using map to get the array of matches, apply map on a
      if (o === input) return b[i]; //check if the value is equal to input, if so return the value from array b for the same index
  })
  console.log(matches); //matches will be array of matches
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BpYZu/)**